# Is it legal to write code like C#?

Tags: c++

Example:

H

```
class MyClass {
    int x,y,z;
public:
    MyClass(int,int,int);
    void X();
    void Y();
    void Z();
};
```

CPP

```
class MyClass {
    int x,y,z;
public:
    MyClass(int x,int y,int z) {
        this->x=x;
        this->y=y;
        this->z=z;
    }
    void X() {
        printf("x = %d;\n",x);
    }
    void Y() {
        printf("y = %d;\n",y);
    }
    void Z() {
        printf("z = %d;\n",z);
    }
};
```

Make it C#-like.
Don't include the header, re-declare the class in the CPP but with method-bodies.
When file include the header then he gets the extern fields\methods and etc from CPP.

It's legal? I can't predict problems from it. There is?

Comment: if it compiles and runs, then its legal. If it doesn't then it is not. simple

Comment: With the double definition makes it extremly fragile.

Comment: @musefan: there's a lot of invalid C++ that compiles cleanly.

Comment: Why are you using `this->x` instead of initializing like `x(x)`?

Comment: it isn't the same class anymore, these are two classes with the same name, I believe

Comment: @Mat. Invalid yes, but not illegal ;)

Comment: You're violating the One Definition Rule. This is not legal.

Comment: @musefan No, that’s wrong. There is a lot of illegal C++ code that compiles cleanly. That is what Mat meant, and he’s right. What, in your mind, is the difference between invalid and illegal anyway (there is one, but it doesn’t apply here)?

Comment: @musefan: what's illegal code? `drugs.sell(plenty)`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I guess we have different definitions of illegal then. To me, illegal is something that is not allowed (i.e. wont compile). Where as invalid is something that doesn't work yet is still allowed to be done

Comment: @musefan: The correct word for your "illegal" is "ill-formed" in the standard.

Comment: You can do this if the compiler allows you but you'll confuse C++ devs that have never use C#

Comment: @Mat: You should be careful posting that kind of code in public places such as SO... meet me round by the backdoor in 10 mins, and bring your favourite text editor

Comment: @musefan This isn’t a matter of opinion. The definition that matters is that of the standard. And as Xeo said, “illegal” isn’t defined there, but it conventionally refers to ill-formed code or one that yields undefined behaviour. Neither is necessarily caught by compilers so whatever definition you use, yours certainly isn’t the right one.

Comment: @musefan: Imagine that a compiler has a bug, whereby it wrongly rejects some bit of code that it *should* be able to compile. Would you say that the code is therefore "illegal"?

Comment: @KonradRudolph. Legal/Illegal wasn't MY definition. It was is the question, and that is what I responded to. There is no point arguing my use of it, I just posted a simple comment based on the terms used by the OP - more in humour than anything else. If I had any intention of answering seriously I would have posted as an answer

Comment: @ruakh: You should [talk to the one that stabs people for asking tricky questions](http://xkcd.com/246/) ;) ...besides, in the eyes of said broken compiler. it would be illegal code yes - again, everyone (even programs) have their own definitions

Comment: Well, nobody will put you in jail for this, I belive. But you may end up in programmer's hell or someting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This falls into the realm of the One Definition Rule. In particular, a requirement that is put on multiple definitions across several TUs of a single program for the same class is:

> [...] — each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens [...]

(Paragraph 5 of 3.2 One definition rule [basic.def.odr])

So even if you 'fixed' the first version to declare the member functions `inline` to match the second version (where providing a definition of the members implicitly declares them `inline`) you would still run afoul of this rule: the function bodies are additional tokens that appear in the one but not in the other.

Comment: the point is that so long as the header is not included in the source file, there is not formal problem since the header is ignored completely

Comment: @Qnan Perhaps you read my answer before I clarified that the rule here is about multiple definitions in separate TUs. The ODR works at the TU level and separately at the program level.

Comment: I'm not arguing with that, just trying to point out the fact that the whole question makes no sense. It compiles only because the header isn't included in any source file.

Comment: @Qnan You can define a class in a TU, then copy and paste that definition in another TU and, given appropriate care, you will have a correct program. Keep in mind the `#include` mechanics are defined in terms of textual inclusion -- the rules really must be tailored to make what I said work. And they are, and it does. From there, it doesn't take much for an inquiring mind to wonder what happen if those two definitions differ in some way. And this is the answer to the question of that inquiring mind.

Comment: very well, I see what you mean now. Do you think there is any advantage to actually doing that?

Answer (score 5):

This isn't allowed by 3.2/5 of the one definition rule section.

> There can be more than one definition of a class type (clause 9),...[other types and conditions that don't matter]
>
> ...and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements.
>   Given such an entity named D defined in more than one translation
>   unit, then
>
> -- each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens;

This clearly prohibits such a mechanism *if the header is included in any other linked translation unit*.

If you want to write C# just write it in C#. Your future maintainers will greatly appreciate it if you write idiomatic C++ instead of a dialect.

Comment: That's not true. Class definitions can be repeated, just not in the same TU. Else you could never have two TUs that used the same class.

Answer (score -1):

A major issue will be circular references: if the code of class `A` contains an instance of class `B`, which itself uses class `A`, compilation will fail.

Separation of a class into its declaration (.h) and definition (.cpp) solves this issue.

But: if you still want to put the class definition in the header file, you can do so by making the class a template, effectively deferring type resolution. But this comes at the cost of an increase in compile time!

Comment: This is the right answer to another question, but not this one.

Comment: OP proposes to have the class declared in the header *and* in the .cpp

Comment: Does he? Sorry, I misunderstood his question then. But I wouldn't call it the "C# way" then...